# How to add posts to blogger?

Tags: android, blogger

I have searched a lot of tutorials, but not found a tutorial to insert posts in blogger using api in the android studio. so anyone have project code for blogger show posts in android app and add posts using api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to check out how to make [network requests](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request) in Android and play with some APIs. You can use [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) library to achieve this.

If you want to upload blogs to `Blogger` using an app then check out the [Blogger API Docs](https://developers.google.com/blogger/)

EDIT - How to do add a post on Blogger -

The official [docs](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/using#AddingAPost) suggests

`You can add a post for a blog by sending a POST request to the post collection URI with a post JSON body` 
So, I'd suggest you use Retrofit to make a [POST request](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/POST.html) to the Blogger API

Also, note that for this you must be authenticated.

Comment: i Checked blogger api. but the problem is i am getting posts from the blogger but not know how to post.

Comment: @PuneetKansal I have edited my answer as to how to make a POST request.